# Process Start time Not displayed

Tags: powershell, process, windows-server-2012

I am trying to check starttime for some of the process running on windows server. Those process are running as services.I tried below command in powershell to do that same.

```
Get-Process|select starttime,id,name
```

But in output it not displaying any starttime, could you please advise why is it happening this way. I could see start time for some of the processes or any process which I start manually(e.g notepad).

```
    StartTime                Id Name
    ---------                -- ----
                           5316 abc
                           6576 xyz
                           6756 efg
```

Comment: `Get-Process|select starttime,id,name` works for me: `4/22/2020 2  :  17  :  05 AM  6164 svchost`. PowerShell 5

Comment: not all processes have a `.StartTime` value. for instance, on my win7/ps5.1 setup, the `spoolsv` service has no start time listed. the _property_ is there, but it is blank _when accessed as a non-elevated user_. when accessed "as admin", it shows up. ///// so, what processes are you seeking that info for?

Comment: The user does have the required access as the process which I am looking are running with that user only.

Comment: @GauravParek - if you want to make sure that your comment reaches a particular person, you should use the same `@UserName` format i used at the beginning of this comment. [*grin*]

Comment: @GauravParek - since you have not provided any of the needed details concerning what fails & what works, i have no idea what you want done ... or how anyone could do anything with the non-existent info you have not provided. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - Main issue I am having is there are some custom services running on windows server and which runs different jobs as per there schedule. When this service starts a job it also starts a process which we can see in task manager, I wanted to see the start time for those particular processes. But the above powershell command mentioned didn't help. And the logged in user on window server is and admin user only so it is not access issue as far as I know. Hope this helps, please let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @GauravParek - _from what i can tell_, the starttime info is sometimes available only to an account that is running as admin on that system. if none of the accounts you are using can see the info, then you likely need to find an account that _does_ have permission to access that info. **_all of that is a guess, not an established fact._** i don't know how to get any deeper into the situation than that, unfortunately.